# Why did Flask start failing with "ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls'"?

Tags: python, flask, pytest, werkzeug

Environment:

```
Python 3.10.11
Flask==2.2.2
```

I run my Flask backend code in docker container, with BASE Image:
`FROM pytorch/pytorch:2.0.1-cuda11.7-cudnn8-runtime`

But when I run the pytest with version `pytest 7.4.2`,

```
pip install pytest
pytest
```

it raised an Error, with logs:

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________ ERROR collecting tests/test_fiftyone_utils_utils.py ______________
ImportError while importing test module '/builds/kw/data-auto-analysis-toolkit-backend/tests/test_fiftyone_utils_utils.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_fiftyone_utils_utils.py:2: in <module>
    import daat  # noqa: F401
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/daat-1.0.0-py3.10.egg/daat/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from daat.app import app
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/daat-1.0.0-py3.10.egg/daat/app/__init__.py:6: in <module>
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/__init__.py:5: in <module>
    from .app import Flask as Flask
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py:30: in <module>
    from werkzeug.urls import url_quote
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py)
```

My codes works well when I directly run it with `python run.py`

`run.py` shown below

```
from daat import app

app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I guess it should be the pytest versions issue, because it used to work well without changing any related code, and I use `pip install pytest` without defined a specific version.

And my backend runs well without pytest.

Comment: Depreciated. Use urllib.parse.urlsplit instead.

Comment: I edited the title because it should be immediately clear that this is about a Flask installation problem, and not for people who are trying to use the Werkzeug API directly.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

I had the same problem. It is because `Werkzeug 3.0.0` was released and Flask doesn't specify the dependency correctly (requirements says `Werkzeug>=2.2.0`). This is why, `Werkzeug 3.0.0` is still installed and `Flask 2.2.2` isn't made for `Werkzeug 3.0.0`.

**Solution**: Just set a fix version for Werkzeug such as `Werkzeug==2.2.2` in your `requirements.txt` and it should work.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use Werkzeug==2.3.x as this was the last version used according to the version specified by flask.

Comment: This is the error I got: `The conflict is caused by: The user requested Werkzeug==2.2; flask 2.2.2 depends on Werkzeug>=2.2.2`

Comment: When using `flask==2.1.3`, it seems forcing `Werkzeug==2.3.7` solves the issue for us. According to our logs, that's the version of `Werkzeug` that still got resolved by `pip` as of end of last week.

Comment: `Werkzeug>=2.2,<3.0` should also work

Comment: Can you do `print(flask.__version__)`? The pinning of `werkzeug` seems to only work by downgrading `flask` from `3.0`. The discrepancy seems to work both ways - if you upgrade to `flask 3.0` things go boom too

Comment: Can also confirm that using `flask==2.2.2` and adding `Werkzeug==2.3.7` fixed this issue for us

Comment: In my case confirmed and user a previos repo version with `pip show Werkzeug` and used that version in my `requirements.txt` file in a line prior to `Flask` like `Werkzeug==2.3.6`

Comment: There is a recent security issue with Werkzeug. For the security issue you may need `werkzeug>=3.0.1` see https://security.snyk.io/package/pip/werkzeug . It is unclear to me how to resolve the Flask-Werkzeug problem then.

Comment: This worked for me, I had to install Werkzeug==2.2.2 using the command pip install Werkzeug==2.2.2

Comment: Thank you for the great simply answer! I note also that applies to the python version on GCP i.e. need to specify - especially a lower version than the most recent available on market

Comment: In early 2024, Flask 3.0.0 and Werkzeug 3.0.1 don't have this issue. Maybe this works for you, @FinnÅrupNielsen

Answer (score 19):

The root cause of this is that `Werkzeug 3.0.0` removed previously deprecated code: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/changes/#version-3-0-0

Please update your Flask version, `Flask 2.2.2` is unsupported: https://github.com/pallets/flask/releases

Anyway, you need to pin Werkzeug yourself then if you insist on using a deprecated version of `Flask`, or if your code is using `url_quote` directly then you can switch to the built-in `urllib`:

```py
from urllib.parse import quote as url_quote
```

Comment: This solution worked for us. The aforementioned one (pinning Werkzeug version) functions as well, but this one is IMHO the correct way.

Comment: Works for url_parse
`#from werkzeug.urls import url_parse`
`from urllib.parse import urlparse as url_parse` [doc.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/urllib.parse.html).

Answer (score 10):

I started getting this error in an update I deployed today, even though I wasn't trying to import "url_quote". `Flask == 2.0.1` .
Setting `Werkzeug==2.2.2` also worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Modify your requirements.txt to include:

`Werkzeug==2.2.x` or `Werkzeug==2.3.x`. Or use `Werkzeug==2.2.2` to be safe.

Comment: Seems pretty much the same as many answers already posted.

Answer (score 5):

```
connexion[swagger-ui]<3
flask>=2.0  
Werkzeug>=2.0
gunicorn>=20.0
```

This combination worked for me and resolved into this:

```
Successfully installed Werkzeug-2.2.3 connexion-2.14.2 flask-2.2.5
```

Python 3.11/3.12

Answer (score 0):

If
you're encountering an issue with the "url_quote" function in your `Flask` application, it's likely due to an incorrect import or a version conflict between `Flask` and `Werkzeug`.

*To resolve this issue, follow the steps below:*

- **Update Your Flask Version**

This step ensures that you have the latest Flask version :

```py
pip install --upgrade Flask
```

---

- **Update pytest**

In some cases, the problem could be related to a pytest version conflict. You can try upgrading pytest to a version that is compatible with your environment using the following command :

```py
pip install --upgrade pytest
```

---

- **Downgrade the Werkzeug Version**

If updating `Flask` and resolving package conflicts doesn't solve the problemconsider using `Werkzeug==2.3.x`, be aware of dependency constraints, and force `Werkzeug==2.3.7` with `Flask==2.1.3` if needed. Specifying a Werkzeug version range like `Werkzeug>=2.2,<3.0` is an adaptable option. Test with `Flask==2.2.2` and `Werkzeug==2.3.7` and verify `Flask` version compatibility. You can also specify the `Werkzeug` version in your `requirements.txt` file, e.g., `Werkzeug==2.3.6`. These steps should help manage version conflicts in your `Flask` application.