# flask with SQLAlchecmys

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-venv

after I run this to use venv

```
python -m venv .venv

source /.venv
```

I'm installing by requirement.txt like this

```
Flask==2.0.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
flask-sqlalchemy==2.5.1
Flask-Migrate==3.1.0
python-dotenv==0.19.1
```

but when I've already set any thing I got the error when I run

```
flask run
```

this is the error
"ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls'"

everything was clear I've already fixed this problem, I just want to know what is the problem

this this list of version before

[version before fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roWPn.png)

after I uninstall "Flask" and reinstall

[version after fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2YHs.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'url\_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213053/importerror-cannot-import-name-url-quote-from-werkzeug-urls)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this question

[ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213053/importerror-cannot-import-name-url-quote-from-werkzeug-urls)

And the answer can be found there. But in short it was a compatibility issue with werkzeug 3 and 2.x.x versions of Flask.

Comment: If you think that question is a duplicate, you should flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: It was my plan, but I don't have enough reputation to flag things. So this was the second best option in my mind.