# cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls'

Tags: exception, werkzeug

cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls' is shown while debugging my app. Py code in visual studio 2022

I tried installing and upgrading werkzeug and flask and i was expecting for the web app to open successfully

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did Flask start failing with "ImportError: cannot import name 'url\_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213053/why-did-flask-start-failing-with-importerror-cannot-import-name-url-quote-fr)