# Error Runnning Python Flask API after creating a docker image

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile, werkzeug

I create a docker image of my python Flask project so that I can deploy it on a ECS container.
When I push my docker image from the pipeline to the container I am receiving the following error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py)

I am not using url_quote in my project files but still this issue persists.

I tried putting 'werkzeug' in my requirements.txt but still facing the same issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213053/why-did-flask-start-failing-with-importerror-cannot-import-name-url-quote-fr - So according to that, flask will pull wrong version o werkzeug and url_quote has been deprecated in the newer versions .. Fix would be to use version of werkzeug < 3.0