ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls' solutions not working
i know this has been asked before so i do apologise, but i cant get any solution working.
try:
    from werkzeug.urls import url_quote  # Werkzeug 0.15.0 and newer
except ImportError:
    try:
        from werkzeug import url_quote  # Werkzeug 0.14.x
    except ImportError:
        # Define a fallback implementation of url_quote using quote_plus from urllib.parse
        def url_quote(s):
            if isinstance(s, str):
                s = s.encode("utf-8")
            return quote_plus(s)

my requirements.txt are:
requests
openai
Flask==2.2.2
Werkzeug==2.3.7

which is the latest of all combinations ive tried.
this is my first time trying to deploy a web app and im doing it on azure, and i cant shake this error!
Im pretty new so i could be making a silly mistake, but im bashing my head against a wall!
if i can get any help, i would seriously appreciate it. Im using python 3.12 id that makes a difference.

Check the version of Werkzeug you have installed by running pip list If its > 3.0.0 then thats likely your issue as it was removed in versions 3.0.0 and above. One solution would be to update Flask and remove the usage of url_quote or install werkzeug 2.3.8

I was told that now it is compatible in 3.0.2?
and to just have flask in the requirements itself with no Werkzeug and that will run.
I should mention locally it works, this is after deployment on Azure i run into the issue.

What about this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77222063/18509670

I have python 3.10 and got this error. I installed following Flask version and it worked.
pip install Flask==3.0.3


I have Python 3.12
requirements.txt
Old:
Flask==2.0.2

New:
Flask==3.0.3
Werkzeug==3.0.3
#pip install Flask==3.0.3
#pip install Werkzeug==3.0.3

